# setPreferredSize is not working

Tags: java, swing

why  `p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200))` is showing error.It say illegal start of type

```
class Menu extends JFrame  {
    JPanel p1=new JPanel();

    //Package p1 does not exist illegal start of type
    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
```

Comment: you're not in a method but in the declarative part. I think you wan' to do that in the constructor

Comment: ok.. got it .Thank you

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign parameter to a class attribute outside a method, constructor or static block.

---

I guess you need a constructor:

```
class Menu extends JFrame  {
    JPanel p1;

    public Menu() {
         p1 = new JPanel();
         p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    }
}
```

---

if you will pass fixed dimension always maybe will be better a static block :

```
class Menu extends JFrame  {
    static JPanel p1;
    // more elements

    static {
         p1 = new JPanel();
         p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
         // more assignements
    }
}
```